# IQueryable<T>.OrderBy<T, object> throws: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

We are using a GenericCriteria class that is used to query an IQueryable without having direct access to it. Basically the query is built in the 'business' layer and passed on to the 'data access' layer. To prevent duplication it needs to be as generic as possible.

Here's a simplified version of the GenericCriteria class:

```
public class GenericCriteria<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Where { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

Resolving the criteria is done by an extension method on IQueryable:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ResolveCriteria<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, GenericCriteria<T> criteria)
{
    query = query.Where(criteria.Where);
    query = query.OrderBy(criteria.OrderBy);
    return query;
}
```

This is how its resolved in the data layer:

```
public ICollection<Person> GetPersons(GenericCriteria<Person> criteria)
{
    using (var context = new EFContext())
    {
        return context.Persons
            .AsQueryable()
            .ResolveCriteria(criteria)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

An example of its usage:

```
var criteria = new GenericCriteria<Person>();
criteria.Where = c => c.Age > 20;
criteria.OrderBy = c => c.Age;

var persons = Data.Instance.GetPersons(criteria);
```

The problem is that Entity Framework is unable to handle the *object* type of the OrderBy expression, throwing an exception:

```
Unable to cast the type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.Object'
```

So what I am now trying to figure out is how I can make the GenericCriteria class accept some kind of generic OrderBy construction so EF will be able to do its thing.

What should I be looking for?

Update:

In case it wasn't clear, I would rather avoid:

```
public class GenericCriteria<T, TKey>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Where { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, TKey>> OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

Because the user of the class might not always want to order, so requiring a type seems a bit dirty.

Comment: Why is your orderBy Interface Property not generic?

Comment: [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) takes 2 generic type parameters.

Comment: Do you have an example of you have initialized / filled the criteria?

Comment: would it be possible to use the `dynamic` keyword?

Comment: OrderBy is not generic, because that would mean the generic type of what you're ordering on needs to be passed to GenericCriteria as well. I would rather avoid this. Or do you have a better solution?

Comment: I have updated the code with an example initialization.

Comment: I can not think of a way to use dynamic in this case. Can you?

Comment: It is possible to rewrite the OrderBy expression to put the cast to the correct type in by creating an expression visitor, but its not trivial. I've never understood the drive to hide IQueryables up the stack, you just end up writing  lot of code to have a crippled version of Linq

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the expression visitor Mant101? Hiding the IQueryable was not my decision unfortunately.

Comment: There is a base class in .net called ExpressionVisitor you can inherit from that can parse and re-write expression. You could have it iterate of order by expression, get the final property (you could be ordering by a nested property), figure out its type and then put a cast into the new expression it produces then use that in the OrderBy. There is an intro here http://pelebyte.net/blog/2011/05/13/doing-simple-things-with-expressionvisitor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want `GenericCriteria` to have two type parameters, while `OrderBy` insists on two type parameters, maybe the best way is to do some dirty work in `ResolveCriteria`, something like the following:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ResolveCriteria<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, GenericCriteria<T> criteria)
{
  query = query.Where(criteria.Where);

  var t = criteria.OrderBy;
  var b = t.Body;
  if (b.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert &&
      ((UnaryExpression)b).Type == typeof(Object)) {
    // Handle simple types, such as short, int, long, etc.
    var bb = ((UnaryExpression)b).Operand;
    var tt = Expression.Lambda(bb, t.Parameters);
    if (bb.Type == typeof(short))
      query = query.OrderBy((Expression<Func<T, short>>)tt);
    else if (bb.Type == typeof(int))
      query = query.OrderBy((Expression<Func<T, int>>)tt);
    else if (...)
      ...
  } else
    // Handle non-simple types, such as string.
    query = query.OrderBy(t);

  return query;
}
```

You'll need an "else if" for each of the simple types; fortunately there aren't many. For a list of simple types please refer to [C# Simple Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691144%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I will rewrite Criteria as below,

```
public class GenericCriteria<T>
{
     public List<Func<IQueryable<T>,IQueryable<T>>> 
          List { get; private set;}

     public GenericCriteria<T>(){
         List = new List<Func<IQueryable<T>,IQueryable<T>>>();
     }

}
```

Resolve

```
public static IQueryable<T> ResolveCriteria<T>(this IQueryable<T> 
       query, GenericCriteria<T> criteria)
{
    foreach(var exp in criteria.List){
       query = exp(query);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Usage

```
var criteria = new GenericCriteria<Person>();
criteria.List.Add( q => q.Where( c => c.Age > 20) );
criteria.List.Add( q => q.OrderBy( c => c.Age ));

var persons = Data.Instance.GetPersons(criteria);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been playing with this idea (using a Func<IQueryable<Person>, IQueryable<Person>> as parameter). The downside of this approach is that I require a reference to Entity Framework in order to use the extension method 'Include' in System.Data.Entity. Not the worst problem to have, but would prefer to avoid.